# Thymeleaf authentication object is either null or empty on an error page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

After successful login authentication was obviously not null, but while still login forcing an error makes the authentication null.

- Spring Boot 1.3.1
- Thymeleaf 2.1.4
- Thymeleaf-Spring4 2.1.4
- Thymeleaf-Extras-SpringSecurity4

error.html (custom error page that handles errors/exception)

```
...          
<header th:include="fragments/menu :: menu"></header>
...
```

menu.html (all menu items does not display during errors/exeception)

```
 ...
 <li sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'MANAGER')">
 ...
 </li>
 ...
 <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a id="logoff" href="#logoff">Log Off</a></li>
 ..
```

Is this behavior expected or am I missing anything? I'm expecting the authentication object to be not null so I can redisplay secured urls links.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Spring Boot that even documented in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling):

> N.B. if you register an ErrorPage with a path that will end up being handled by a Filter (e.g. as is common with some non-Spring web
>   frameworks, like Jersey and Wicket), then the Filter has to be
>   explicitly registered as an ERROR dispatcher (the default
>   FilterRegistrationBean does not include the ERROR dispatcher type).

And example:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean myFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    ...
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    return registration;
}
```

See also [related issue in Spring Boot tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1048).

But you can configure it even simpler since 1.3.1 (see [#4505](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4505)) by adding the following line to `application.properties`:

```
security.filter-dispatcher-types: ASYNC, FORWARD, INCLUDE, REQUEST, ERROR
```

Comment: Creating a FilterRegistrationBean and overriding the default dispatch-types did not help resolve the issue. However, following [issue # 5638](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5638)  provided a workaround by suppressing the default BasicErrorController. So far this is working well with Spring Boot 1.3.1 + Thymeleaf 2.1.4.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the [thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity) github page.

You should add the SpringSecurity dialect to your Template Engine:

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps