# Show user informations in header using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working with **Spring** and **Thymeleaf**, I am trying to show user information (username ) in the header throw all pages.

> **header.html**

```
<div th:fragment="logout" class="logout" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">     
        Logged in user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span> |                   
        Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>             
        <div>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">                  
                <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem :

**STEP 1 :** Create an CommunAdviceController

```
public class CommunAdviceController {

@Autowired
UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository;

@ModelAttribute("nomEtPrenom")
public String nomEtPrenomUtilisateur() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Utilisateur util = utilisateurRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName()) ;    
    if( util != null) {         
        return util.getUsername();
    }else {
    return "Anonyme";
    }
}
```

}

Note that in my case i am getting the mail adresse of the user as `getUsername`

**STEP 2 :** Call the method in the HTML

```
<a href ="#" th:text="${nomEtPrenom}" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

And the job is done.

Hope that it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dependency to the appropriate version of `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`.

Then add the xmlns to you html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
            xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

and you can do

```
<div th:text="${#authentication.name}">
    The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
</div>
```

More info about the [Spring Security Integration module](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)

Comment: it's showing the following error `Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null`

Comment: it means authentication object is null..could you verify if authentication object is not null when this header page loads

Comment: how can i do it ?!?

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024656/thymeleaf-authentication-object-is-either-null-or-empty-on-an-error-page and https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

Comment: After many tries `hasAuthority('ADMIN')` and `hasRole('ADMIN')` and `sec:authentication="name"` doesn't work and the output doesn't show anything any idea ?!?